# Operator<< in base class not visible in derived class

Tags: c++, overloading, visibility, operator-keyword, base-class

I'm getting this error message:

> Operator<< in base class not visible in derived class

My Code:

```
class Dummy {};

class SomethingElse {};

class XBase
{
public:
    void noop() {};
    void operator <<(Dummy d) {};
};

class A : public XBase
{
public:
    void operator << (SomethingElse s) {}  // When commenting out statement: No compile error!
};

int main()
{
    Dummy dummy;
    SomethingElse somethingelse;
    XBase X;
    A a;

    X << dummy;
    a << dummy;         // why is Xbase::operator<< invisible, it's a different type
    a << somethingelse;
}
```

Compiler error messages:

> error C2679 : binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right - hand operand of type 'Dummy' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>
> message : could be 'void A::operator <<(SomethingElse)'
> message : while trying to match the argument list '(A, Dummy)'
>
> void operator <<(Dummy d) {}; in the base class "Xbase" becomes
> invisible by declaring any  void operator <<(SomethingElse d) {}; in a
> derived class.

Why is this?

Tested with Visual Studio 19 C++ Compiler and GCC 7 under Linux (cross compiled with VS Studio 19)

Comment: (Great first question with a perfect [MCVE] and explanation in comments by the way!)

Comment: Why can't the compiler decide on the different parameter type like by function overloading? Is this the point where "name hiding" and "polymorphism" byte each other over the boundaries of base and derived classes?

Comment: If you're interested, you can read more about why this happens here: https://www.programmerinterview.com/c-cplusplus/c-name-hiding/

Comment: So the elegant (?) solution is to add " using XBase::operator<<;" to class A.

Comment: That is correct.